# Border and -ve margin causes word wrap on Firefox, but not Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox

Here's an example of code to place a border around span tags on hover:

### CSS

```
p {
    background-color: #def;
    width: 137px; /* chosen so the text *just* fits, may need to alter
                   * for different browser or OS 
                   */
}
span {
    margin: 0;
}
span:hover {
    margin: -2px;
    border: 2px solid #336;    
}
```

### HTML

```
<p>
    <span>hover</span> <span>over</span> <span>the</span> <span>words</span>
</p>
```

(See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/sS7vY/)

It uses a -ve margin to compensate for the border and avoid the text shifting position on hover.

On Firefox, hovering over the very last word causes it to wrap over to the next line, which I want to avoid. On Chrome it behaves as I intended and never wraps.

Is this a Firefox bug that needs reporting?

Is there a way to prevent this wrapping in Firefox, in a way that works for arbitrary text? (i.e. adding a couple more pixels width to the outer `<p>` is not a valid solution!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's a bug in either browser as I'm not familiar with the inline box model, but using an outline instead of a border [seems to work well](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/sS7vY/1) as outlines don't affect box sizing, even on inline-level boxes:

```
span:hover {
    outline: 2px solid #336;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I forded a working solution of your's : jsfiddle.net/dgY4J

It seems to be a mixed of 'box-sizing' and available width situation.

Also, if you use the [css box-sizing](https://www.google.ca/#q=box-sizing%3aborder-box), you won't have to deal with borders with the negative margins.

One last tip : **chosen so the text just fits, may need to alter for different browser or OS**  || it will do the oposite. No browsers render font type the same.

Comment: @BoltClock Humm box-sizing on inline elements ? Thanks for the tip. I'll give a double check NOW, but i don't think you are right.